# is not bound to a legal value during translation

Tags: alloy

I would like to know a bit more about the bounding this error relates to.

I have an alloy model for which I create an instance manually (by writting it down in XML).
This instance is readable and the A4Solution can be correctly displayed.
But when I try to evaluate an expression in this instance using the eval() function, I receive this error message, though the field name and type of the exprvar retrieved from the model is exactly the same as the one in the instance..

I would like to know what does this bounding consist of. What are the properties taken into consideration to tell that one element of the instance is bounded to one element of the model.

Is the hidden ID figuring in the XML somewhere taken into consideration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing the set of Signatures defined in the metamodel while reading the A4Solution solved my problem.
Thus changing:

```
solution = A4SolutionReader.read(null, new XMLNode(f));
```

by

```
solution = A4SolutionReader.read(mm.getAllReachableSigs(), new XMLNode(f));
```

solved this illegal bounding issue

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to know what does this bounding consist of.

It means that every free variable (i.e., relation in Kodkod) has to be given a bound before asking the solver to solve the formula.

> What are the properties taken into consideration to tell that one element of the instance is bounded to one element of the model.

The instance XML file contains and exact value (a tuple set) for each and every sig and field from the model; those tuple sets are exactly the bounds that should be used when evaluating expressions.  I'm not sure how exactly you are trying to use the Alloy API; but recreating the bounds from the XML file should (mostly) be handled by the API behind the scene.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your quick reply. I'm trying to use the Alloy API in an unconventional way (I am definitely aware of it) as I'm mainly interested now in working at the instance level, thing which is not made easy by the API implementation. 

About this specific problem, I am actually trying, given an A4Solution and an AlloyProjection, to build a new A4Solution which would contain all the elements that would remains after applying the given projection.

Comment: Rather than implementing my own projection, and as A4Solutions do not allows the edition of instances anyway, I decided to use the StaticProjector.project methods that takes an AlloyInstance rather than an A4Solution. I obtained the AlloyInstance by reading the XML of the previously mention A4Solution. I then apply the projection on it and obtain a new AlloyInstance. As there are no facilities available in my knowledge to go from AlloyInstance to A4Solution, I wrote my own "XML writer".

Comment: The XML is valid, as once i parse it as an A4Solution, I can display this latter without problem. But when I try to evaluate an element of the CompModule used to generate the genuine A4Solution; this "bounding problem" occur.

PS: sorry for the multiple comments, the character limitation prevented me from posting everything in one comment ...

Answer (score 3):

Judging by your last comment to my previous answer, your problem might be related to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568069/how-to-evaluate-in-a-given-solution-a-predicate-declared-in-a-different-model-th).

In a nutshell, if you are trying to evaluate AST expression objects obtained from one "alloy world" (`CompModule`) against a solution that was entirely recreated from an XML file, you will get exactly that error.  For example, if you have two `PrimSig` objects, `s1` and `s2`, and they both have the same name (e.g., both were obtained by parsing `sig S {...}`), they are not "Java equals" (`s1.equals(s2)` returns `false`); the same holds for the underlying Kodkod relations/variables.  So if you then try to evaluate `s1` in a context which has a bound only for `s2`, you'll get an error saying that `s1` is not bound.

Comment: Yes, I remembered that post.
The problem is the same but here my question was asked from a different angle.
I wanted basically to know, how to "force a bounding" by understanding its nature.
As I "master" the XML representation of A4Solutions, I wanted to know how to encode a field or a signature, such that it is bounded correctly. (Is giving the same ID, parentID, and name sufficient ?)

Comment: I don't think the Alloy API lets you do that.  Kodkod accepts bounds for individual relations, whereas Alloy accepts a scope (for sigs and Ints).  Therefore, you cannot directly provide a bound for, e.g., a `PrimSig` object.  If you want to mess with the bounds, you will have to modify the `A4Solution` class, find the place where it calls the Kodkod `solve` method, and modify the `Bounds` object it passes to it.  The Kodkod API for adding relation bounds is straightforward: for each relation you can provide a pair of lower and upper bounds using the `bound` method.

Comment: You could actually try adding a scope for your "outside" sigs (see the `CommandScope` class; command scopes can be defined for commands only, via the `Command` class).  I'm not sure if this approach would work without having to make any modifications to the Alloy source files.

Comment: I will give it a try later and let you know if I figure out something.

Thank you for your highly appreciated support :)